# Bad tensor shape when using tensorflow drop_remainder

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a `tf.data.Dataset` from a generator. I want to make sure all of my batches have the exact same size, so I'm calling `.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)` on my Dataset. Here's the relevant code:

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: map(tuple, train_generator),
    (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    (
        tf.TensorShape([batch_size, crop_height, crop_width, 3]),
        tf.TensorShape([batch_size, crop_height, crop_width, 3]),
    ),
)

val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: map(tuple, val_generator),
    (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    (
        tf.TensorShape([batch_size, crop_height, crop_width, 3]),
        tf.TensorShape([batch_size, crop_height, crop_width, 3]),
    ),
)

my_train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
my_val_data = val_data.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

But I get this error when I run it:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: input must be 4-dimensional[4,4,64,64,48] [Op:FusedBatchNormV3]
```

I get this error because I'm batching the data twice (`batch_size` is 4 in my error message). I tried to replace the `batch_size` with `None` in the `.from_generator` command, but I get the same error. If I remove the first argument completely like so:

```
(tf.TensorShape([options["crop_height"], options["crop_width"], 3]),
            tf.TensorShape([options["crop_height"], options["crop_width"], 3]),
        )
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (4, 128, 128, 3) where an element of shape (128, 128, 3) was expected.
```

How can I use `drop_remainder` without batching the data twice?

EDIT:

Adding code associated with generators:

```
class BaseGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(
        self,
        image_filenames,
        label_filenames,
        batch_size=1,
        is_train=True,
        preprocess=None,
        augment=None,
        height=128,
        width=128,
        shuffle=False,
    ):
        self.indices = np.arange(0, len(image_filenames))
        self.image_filenames = np.array(image_filenames)
        self.label_filenames = np.array(label_filenames)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.is_train = is_train
        self.preprocess = preprocess
        self.augment = augment
        self.crop_height = height
        self.crop_width = width
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()  # shuffle data
    
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.indices) / float(self.batch_size)))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        min_index = index * self.batch_size
        max_index = min((index + 1) * self.batch_size, len(self.indices))
        batch_indices = self.indices[min_index:max_index]
        return self.generate(self.image_filenames[batch_indices], self.label_filenames[batch_indices])
    
    def __call__(self):
        return next(iter(self))
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.is_train and self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indices)
    
    def generate(self, image_filenames, label_filenames):
        X = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.crop_height, self.crop_width, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.crop_height, self.crop_width), dtype=np.float32,)
    
        for i, (image_fn, label_fn) in enumerate(zip(image_filenames, label_filenames)):
            image = utils.load_image(image_fn)
            label = utils.load_image(label_fn)
    
            if self.augment:
                augmented = self.augment(image=image, mask=label)
                image = augmented["image"]
                label = augmented["mask"]
    
            if self.preprocess:
                image = self.preprocess(image)
    
            label = np.float32(helpers.one_hot_it(label=label))
    
            X[i, :, :, :] = image
            y[i, :, :, :] = label
    
        return X, y


train_generator = BaseGenerator(
    image_filenames=train_input_names,
    label_filenames=train_output_names,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    is_train=True,
    preprocess=preprocessing,
    augment=None,
    height=128,
    width=128,
)

val_generator = BaseGenerator(
    image_filenames=val_input_names,
    label_filenames=val_output_names,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    is_train=False,
    preprocess=preprocessing,
    augment=None,
    height=128,
    width=128,
)
```

Comment: Please add the computation graph as well as input data shapes.

Comment: The input images are (128, 128, 3). I'll have to look at how to add the computational graph

Comment: Please show your code of `train_generator` and `val_generator` for debug purpose, even better if you could provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added the generator code. I know it's still not a full example though.

Comment: Did you try using `output_signature` argument instead of `output_types` and `output_shapes` in `from_generator`? since it's the recommended way to call `from_generator`, also where did you get error exactly? can you show the full error trace?

Comment: I tried it and got an error... looks like it was only added in version 2.4 - I'm on version 2.3 and it's not the [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

Comment: @jss367 Is my answer helpful? If that's not the case, I'll be happy to help you further.

Comment: @rvinas Yes it is, that you. I'm still working through it - hope to finish getting it working tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, the issue is that you are batching your data twice. To overcome this problem, you can:

1. First, define a generator that yields single images (e.g. without batch dimension).
2. Then, group your examples into batches using the method [batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) of `tf.data.Dataset`.

---

In order to redefine `BaseGenerator` so that it yields single images, you can follow the next steps.

First, in the `__init__` method, remove `batch_size` because it is no longer needed:

```
def __init__(
        self,
        image_filenames,
        label_filenames,
        is_train=True,
        preprocess=None,
        augment=None,
        height=128,
        width=128,
        shuffle=False,
):
    self.indices = np.arange(0, len(image_filenames))
    self.image_filenames = np.array(image_filenames)
    self.label_filenames = np.array(label_filenames)
    self.is_train = is_train
    self.preprocess = preprocess
    self.augment = augment
    self.crop_height = height
    self.crop_width = width
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()  # shuffle data
```

Second, adapt the method `generate` so that it yields a single example:

```
def generate(self, image_filename, label_filename):
    image = utils.load_image(image_filename)
    label = utils.load_label(label_filename)

    if self.augment:
        augmented = self.augment(image=image, mask=label)
        image = augmented["image"]
        label = augmented["mask"]

    if self.preprocess:
        image = self.preprocess(image)

    label = np.float32(helpers.one_hot_it(label=label))

    X = image  # Shape=(self.crop_height, self.crop_width, 3)
    Y = label  # Shape=(self.crop_height, self.crop_width)

    return X, y
```

Third, in the method `__getitem__`, pass only one filename:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.generate(self.image_filenames[index], self.label_filenames[index])
```

Finally, exclude the batch dimension when defining your `tf.data.Dataset`:

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: map(tuple, train_generator),
    (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    (
        tf.TensorShape([crop_height, crop_width, 3]),
        tf.TensorShape([crop_height, crop_width]),
    ),
)

my_train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

it = iter(my_train_data)
x, y = next(it)

print(x.shape)  # (4, 128, 128, 3)
print(y.shape)  # (4, 128, 128)
```